# How can I create a hexbin layer using the SQL and CartoCSS parameters in cartodb.js?

Tags: postgis, javascript, sql, carto, cartocss

CartoDB has a great hexbin visualization wizard baked into the client dashboard:

[image]

However, I like using cartodb.js to customize events and interactions; in particular, I'd like to make styles dependent on map zoom level. Recognizing that the hexbin visualization is a combination of [SQL](https://gist.github.com/andrewxhill/8360694#file-index-html-L46-L60) and [CartoCSS](https://gist.github.com/andrewxhill/8360694#file-index-html-L46-L60) parameter configuration, what are the ideal functions to pass to CartoDB to return hexes with cartodb.js?

Comment: I just discovered [this](https://gist.github.com/wboykinm/8959996), which may make things easier.

Comment: If you haven't seen it, [this](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/wiki/CDB_HexagonGrid) is handy as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, maybe a bit ugly but I put a lot of functionality in here

http://bl.ocks.org/andrewxhill/9003528

It includes

- create an initial layer on the fly
- a hover to the layer
- after timeout, changing the size of the density grid
- recalculating a style to go along with the new size

I think it will get you pretty far. Note, you could make the style calculation before any createLayer event, and you would be able to then apply the initial style without ever knowing it.

One key thing to notice is that the tiler uses `!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!` whereas the SQL API needs to use, `CDB_XYZ_Resolution(some zoom)`

Comment: Holy. Crap. Amazing.

Answer (score 1):

CartoDB documentation for [advanced concepts](http://developers.cartodb.com/documentation/advanced_concepts.html) includes a function `CDB_HexagonGrid` that could be useful for you, you have some [example of use on the wiki of their github account](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/wiki/CDB_HexagonGrid)

There is actually an [example](http://vizzuality.s3.amazonaws.com/hexagon/index.html) of a grid regenerated for each zoom level that may also help.

Comment: FYI this is the query we use inside the CartoDB UI https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/blob/master/lib/assets/javascripts/cartodb/models/carto.js#L688